# What's a RAM efficient solution for web files & MySQL backup to Amazon S3 on a VPS?

Tags: mysql, amazon-s3, backup, vps, database-backups

Here's the current solution:
http://www.tech-problems.com/backup-mysql-and-files-on-amazon-ec2-to-s3/

I'm currently using a PHP CLI script that runs nightly using cron. The problem is before the script runs for the first time there's 300MB of RAM in use then after it runs RAM doubles to almost 700MB. The web files backup uses the most memory. After the scripts run the RAM says used.

Anyone with VPS / low memory setups that can suggest a better - more efficient - alternative to backup web files and MySql database to s3?

Comment: what process is holding onto the memory?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go for CDP 3.0 backup solution. I am taking backup of all my VPS nodes (Linux & Windows) using CDP 3.0. It is fast, efficient and takes incremental backup of your VPS.